# selected checkbox deselecting automatically in owl carousal html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, carousel

i have created a checkbox below owl carousel, the complete code is like below:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  slideBy: 5,
  navText: [
    "<i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i>",
    "<i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i>"
  ],
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.owl-dot {
  display: none !important;
}

.carousel-wrap {
  margin: 90px auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
}


/* fix blank or flashing items on carousel */

.owl-carousel .item {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* end fix */

.owl-nav>div {
  margin-top: -26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  color: #cdcbcd;
}

.owl-nav i {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.owl-nav i:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.owl-nav .owl-prev {
  left: -30px;
}

.owl-nav .owl-prev:hover {
  color: none;
}

.owl-nav .owl-next {
  right: -30px;
}

.owl-prev,
.owl-next {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block !important;
  border: 0px solid black;
}

.owl-prev {
  left: -80px !important;
}

.owl-next {
  right: -80px !important;
}

.owl-prev i,
.owl-next i {
  transform: scale(5, 5);
  color: #F2136E;
}

.item img {
  height: 150px !important;
  width: 150px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div style="position: relative; " class="row">
    <h3 style="font-weight: bold; margin-left:15%; color:#F2136E;  top:0px; left:0; position: absolute;">Package 1</h3>



    <div class="carousel-wrap" style="margin-top: 40px;">
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/cakes/5e68d81747d50d9c7b5689f109f042c9.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/cakes/dd2823a1ef8e776b14fdbcc854b92c74.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/cakes/317212cea9b87a4f0bea35202156bc75.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/decorations/20f1c60528bee31338236723575cb56a.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/decorations/cff57350b0abc1f2e95f6022c41f8e8a.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/food_items/481536225d682ae9712f67479d278e51.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/food_items/213687a10d166d87b5567fd8ace1ebdb.jpeg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/food_items/57dd3add7b0e1351c2633e6c1a5c00fc.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/food_items/436e1d3e7856b75314477de53c7f3526.jpeg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/food_items/265e17defc7bdb44d7b6d805d3b06860.jpeg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





</div>
```

this is my live URL : [enter link description here](https://www.booktheparty.in/packagedetails)
if I select any checkbox and move the slider , mainly when I click the left nav button to move the slider. the selected item gets deselected, sometimes if i move click the nav button again, the disappeared selection displays as selected. cn anyone please tell me how to fix this, thanks in advance

Comment: This is likely due to the fact that these type of sliders use _clones_ of the elements, to enable seamless “endless” sliding. When you see an item sliding in “again”, it is likely not actually the original item, but a clone. So you would probably have to implement a solution that toggles the checkbox status in the clone of an element., resp. the other direction as well (when checkbox state gets changed in a clone, you’ll have to apply that to the original.)

Comment: @CBroe is there any alternative way to fix it bro, can you show as an example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write event handler for checkboxes so whenever checkbox is change you can check if the state of checkbox is checked or not depending on this add some class i.e : `checked` to the checkbox which is clicked and also to the original checkbox using `data-id`.Then , on `changed.owl.carousel` event add `attr("checked", "true");` to all checkboxes which has `checked` class.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  slideBy: 5,
  navText: [
    "<i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i>",
    "<i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i>"
  ],
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
  //add checked true to all checkboxes which has .checked class
  $(".owl-carousel .checked").attr("checked", "true");
});
//on chnage of checkbox is will get called
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
  //get data-id
  var data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).addClass("checked") //add class checked
    $(".owl-carousel input[data-id=" + data_id + "]").addClass("checked")
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("checked") //remove checked
    $(".owl-carousel input[data-id=" + data_id + "]").removeClass("checked")
  }


})
```

```css
/* fix blank or flashing items on carousel */

.owl-carousel .item {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* end fix */

.owl-nav>div {
  margin-top: -26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  color: #cdcbcd;
}

.owl-nav i {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.owl-nav i:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.owl-nav .owl-prev {
  left: -30px;
}

.owl-nav .owl-prev:hover {
  color: none;
}

.owl-nav .owl-next {
  right: -30px;
}

.owl-prev,
.owl-next {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block !important;
  border: 0px solid black;
}

.owl-prev {
  left: -80px !important;
}

.owl-next {
  right: -80px !important;
}

.owl-prev i,
.owl-next i {
  transform: scale(5, 5);
  color: #F2136E;
}

.item img {
  height: 150px !important;
  width: 150px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div style="position: relative; " class="row">
    <h3 style="font-weight: bold; margin-left:15%; color:#F2136E;  top:0px; left:0; position: absolute;">Package 1</h3>



    <div class="carousel-wrap" style="margin-top: 40px;">
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/cakes/5e68d81747d50d9c7b5689f109f042c9.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check ">
            <!--added data-id to identify checkbox-->
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" data-id="1">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/cakes/dd2823a1ef8e776b14fdbcc854b92c74.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" data-id="2">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/cakes/317212cea9b87a4f0bea35202156bc75.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" data-id="3">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/decorations/20f1c60528bee31338236723575cb56a.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" data-id="4">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/decorations/cff57350b0abc1f2e95f6022c41f8e8a.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" data-id="5">
            <!--<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2"></label>-->
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/food_items/481536225d682ae9712f67479d278e51.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" data-id="6">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/food_items/213687a10d166d87b5567fd8ace1ebdb.jpeg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" data-id="7">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/food_items/57dd3add7b0e1351c2633e6c1a5c00fc.jpg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" data-id="8">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/food_items/436e1d3e7856b75314477de53c7f3526.jpeg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" data-id="9">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item"><img src="https://admin.booktheparty.in/assets/images/food_items/265e17defc7bdb44d7b6d805d3b06860.jpeg">
          <div style=" text-align:center; margin-top:5% " class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" data-id="10">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```